Minimal BASH like line editing is supported GRUB Error
I have an issue with my Gigabyte laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 (no dual boot).
I encountered the famous "Minimal BASH like line editing is supported GRUB Error". I have to restart it multiple times until it boots correctly.
Following a few tutorials and previous posts, I installed Boot-Repair and ran it. Please find the logs here.
============================== Boot Repair Summary ==============================

modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-48-generic

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p2,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


/dev/nvme0n1p2/boot/efi not empty

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub

=================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/nvme0n1p2 ===================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-48-generic
modprobe efivars

efibootmgr -v (filtered) before grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,86051ee7-65b0-4465-b6b2-d06cee76c9c6,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

uname -r
6.8.0-48-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v (filtered) after grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,86051ee7-65b0-4465-b6b2-d06cee76c9c6,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
Warning: NVram was not modified.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on nvme0n1p2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: NVIDIA Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic root=UUID=a549d070-77ea-4133-8acf-76198ffb5765 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/nvme0n1p2 ext4  468G  353G   93G  80% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: FB01(7.1) from INSYDE Corp.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,86051ee7-65b0-4465-b6b2-d06cee76c9c6,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: AD593713-7F1A-47BF-BE74-A7955FC459DD
           Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
nvme0n1p2 1050624 1000214527 999163904 476.4G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:SSSTC CA6-8D512:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:512GB:512GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
nvme0n1                                                                                              
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     E36B-5824                            86051ee7-65b0-4465-b6b2-d06cee76c9c6       EFI System Partition
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4     a549d070-77ea-4133-8acf-76198ffb5765 04afec98-d08a-4f27-9ad5-9354d04f5f81       

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                    Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2                        92G  75% /
efivarfs                            30.4K  87% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p2                      ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid a549d070-77ea-4133-8acf-76198ffb5765 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   a549d070-77ea-4133-8acf-76198ffb5765
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p2/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=a549d070-77ea-4133-8acf-76198ffb5765 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=E36B-5824  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p2: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 366.129154205 = 393.128185856  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
   8.366428375 = 8.983384064    boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 399.155487061 = 428.589940736  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic                  1
   8.366428375 = 8.983384064    boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic                  2
 399.155487061 = 428.589940736  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 384.641597748 = 413.005770752  boot/initrd.img                                6
 128.360347748 = 137.825873920  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic               7
 384.641597748 = 413.005770752  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic               6
 128.360347748 = 137.825873920  boot/initrd.img.old                            7

=================== nvme0n1p2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec  2  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec  2  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec  2  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec  2  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Sep 20  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec  2  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec  2  2022 41_custom

Boot-Repair did find a problem with grub and reinstalled it (from what I understand), however when I rebooted the laptop, I encountered the Minimal BASH-like error again. So Boot-Repair did not seem to solve the error.
Please find below the list of my BIOS settings. I have written only the ones that I think are relevant, but I am not familiar with them, so don't hesitate if some info is missing.
EFI > ubuntu (002251400C52-SSSTC CA6-8D512) Enabled
UEFI Setting > Network Stack > Disabled

TPM Configuration > Clear TPM > Disabled

Advanced Chipset Control > UEFI OS Fast Boot > Enabled
Enable VMD controller > Disabled

Secure Boot Database > Installed and Locked
Secure Boot Status > Disabled
User Customized Security > No

Enforce Secure Boot > Disabled
Erase all Secure Boot Settings > Disabled
Restore Secure Boot to Factory Settings > Disabled

Boot Manager
    only one option ( ubuntu (002251400C52-SSSTC CA6-8D512))


Are you able to boot recovery mode from grub menu. You have to press escape after vendor logo & before menu normally appears. If rebooting multiple times works, it may be another setting in UEFI settings. Check settings. What brand/model system?

Thanks for your answer. I haven't try to boot recovery mode but, yes, after multiple times (2-5 depending) it reboots normally.
I looked at the BIOS settings but I am not too familiar with them. The laptop is a Gigabyte, I would need to check the exact model.

I have edited my post with some UEFI settings. Do you see something I should try to change?

Have not seen many Gigabyte laptops. Most posts have been on motherboards. Often issue has been related to older UEFI. Have you updated UEFI firmware & if SSD its firmware to latest available?
